# What is $\int_0^{\infty}\!e^{-x^2}e^{-ae^{bx^2}}\,dx$?

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

I've been trying without success to evaluate
$$
{\Large\int_0^{\infty}\!e^{-x^2}e^{\Large \,-ae^{\,bx^2}}\,dx}.
$$
It's not in my integral tables. Wolfram online integrator won't do it. It doesn't seem to be amenable to a contour integral method, and the method of integrating $e^{−x^2}$ alone doesn't work either. I'm trying to solve a PDE that shows up in a financial mathematics context and have made a lot of progress. If I could do this integral, I would have a closed form. Any halep would be appreciated.

Comment: I put your question into $\LaTeX$, please make sure the edit is what you intended.

Comment: That's what I intended. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't brushed up on my complex analysis in a while, but since this function is even, can we view the integral as $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{-ae^{bx^2}}\,dx$, and then use residues? It looks like it has no poles other than the one at infinity, so we can view the integral over $\Bbb{R}$ as an integral along the "equator" of the Riemann Sphere, which could be deformed to a small circle around the point at infinity.

Comment: Doesn't the function have $0$ residue at infinity because of the $x^2$ terms?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only approach to solve this integral is to apply the series decomposition approach.

Note that the following procedure works only when $a=0$ and $(a\neq0$ and $b\leq0)$ . (Think why?)

$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}e^{-ae^{bx^2}}~dx$

$=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(ae^{bx^2})^n}{n!}dx$

$=\int_0^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^ne^{(bn-1)x^2}}{n!}dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^n\sqrt{\pi}}{2n!\sqrt{1-bn}}$

Comment: Are you sure about this result?  What happens when $b n \gt 1$?

Comment: $b<0$ so this isn't true

Comment: I think the $\sqrt{1-bn}$ term should be in the numerator, and there should be no 2 in the denominator, the integral is over $[0,\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be late to the party and this is really just a comment on Harry Peter's answer, but while there seems to be no closed form solution of your integral, there are closed form bounds on it (at least under the hypotheses $a \geq 0$ and $b < 0$). In fact, if we denote the value of your integral by $J(a,b)$, then
$$
\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} e^{-a / \sqrt{1+b}} \leq J(a,b) \leq \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} e^{-a}.
$$
This may be good enough for what you have in mind. (Also note the right-hand side bound is particularly nice since it is independent of $b$.)

I'll sketch the idea and leave the final verifications to you. Consider Harry's series solution
$$
J(a,b) = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{a^n}{\sqrt{1-bn}}.
$$
Ignore for the moment that $(-1)^n$ isn't always positive. Then we could bound each term in the sum as
$$
\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{a^n}{\sqrt{(1-b)^n}}
\leq
\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{a^n}{\sqrt{1-bn}}
\leq
\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} a^n,
$$
which would give the bounds I wrote. To get around that $(-1)^n$ is sometimes negative we consider the series expansions of each of the bounds, sum them as even $+$ odd terms and try to bound those, that is, we show that
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\Bigl( \frac{1}{(2n)!}\frac{a^{2n}}{(1+b)^n} 
&- \frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\frac{a^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{(1+b)^{2n+1}}} \Bigr)\\
&\leq 
\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Bigl( 
\frac{1}{(2n)!} \frac{a^{2n}}{\sqrt{1-b2n}}
-\frac{1}{(2n+1)!} \frac{a^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1-b(2n+1)}}
\Bigr) \\
&\leq 
\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\Bigl(\frac{1}{(2n)!} a^{2n} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)!} a^{2n+1} \Bigr)
\end{align}
by proving the inequalities hold for each of the $n$-th terms. We can simplify each term by cancelling the $\pi$ factors, multiplying by $(2n+1)!$ and factoring $a^{2n}$ out. Then it is not hard, but takes a little elementary work, to show the inequalities holds for each term. (Note that we do *not* show that any of these is always $\geq 0$ -- indeed for a fixed $n$ and big $a$ that won't be true.)

Comment: For the cases of $a>0$ and $b>0$ , $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{-ae^{bx^2}}$ still converges to $0$ , but does the integral still converge?

Comment: Yes, just estimate $exp(bx^2) \geq 1$ for all big enough $x$, this shows convergence. We can maybe use basic estimates on exp to get estimates of the solution then.

Comment: But how to express the integral in some series forms for the cases of $a>0$ and $b>0$ ? @Ron Gordon dislike my answer because I caanot do this.

Comment: @HarryPeter: No idea, the obvious series expansion doesn't converge in that case. There may not be a series expansion then. Even if there is, what do we gain? The one we have doesn't give all that much information and if we want to estimate the integral (numerically or analytically) the integrand probably already contains enough information to do that effectively.