# Integrating exponential of multiple exponentials

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, bounded-variation, exponential-sum

I have a integral term that looks similar to $\int_0^\infty\exp(-u-ae^{-c_1u}-be^{-c_2u})\,du$ where the constants $a,b,c_1,c_2>0$. For the case where $b=0$ I can use the answer from: [Integrating exponential of exponential function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536391/integrating-exponential-of-exponential-function/536916?noredirect=1#536916).

Using a similar approach where I let $t=\exp(-u)$, and taking the simpler case where a=b=1, I get:
$$\int_0^1\exp(-(t^{c_1}+t^{c_2}))\,dt$$

Using this or otherwise, how would I progress?

In the event that there is no analytical solution, what would be an **exponential** lower-bound on the function, $\exp(-u-ae^{-c_1u}-be^{-c_2u})$ that takes into account all the constants, $a,b,c_1,c_2$

Answer (score 3):

$\int_0^\infty e^{-u-ae^{-c_1u}-be^{-c_2u}}~du$

$=\int_\infty^0e^{-ae^{-c_1u}-be^{-c_2u}}~d(e^{-u})$

$=\int_0^1e^{-au^{c_1}-bu^{c_2}}~du$

$=\int_0^1\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(au^{c_1}+bu^{c_2})^n}{n!}du$

$=\int_0^1\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^nC_k^n(au^{c_1})^k(bu^{c_2})^{n-k}}{n!}du$

$=\int_0^1\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^na^kb^{n-k}u^{c_2n+(c_1-c_2)k}}{k!(n-k)!}du$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^na^kb^{n-k}u^{c_2n+(c_1-c_2)k+1}}{k!(n-k)!(c_2n+(c_1-c_2)k+1)}\right]_0^1$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^na^kb^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!(c_2n+(c_1-c_2)k+1)}$

Only in some very special cases this integral can have chance for expressable in terms of known special functions $\left(\text{e.g. when}\dfrac{c_1}{c_2}\text{or}\dfrac{c_2}{c_1}=1~\text{or}~2~\text{or}~3\right)$ .

Comment: In the event that they are 1,2 or 3 as you mentioned which special function were you thinking of